# Encrypt session between two servers

Tags: java, security, rsa

The architecture of my system is such that the mysql database lies on a particular machine while the application code lies on another. How do I encrypt/protect the data passing between them?

I have a slight clue that this should be probably done through RSA (session encryption). Can someone please point me the correct direction?

Comment: If it cannot be done at the application level, it can be done at the OS level: VPN, ssh tunnel,...

Comment: @BGR is right, you should do that on the OS level, typical VPN usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using JDBC over SSL.There is a [guide on configuring SSL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html) on the mysql website. I've done this using Oracle recently and it works really well. It does degrade performance somewhat so carefully consider what you are sending securely.